# Why won't my Hammerspoon alert fade on close despite being supplied a fadeout duration?

Tags: lua, hammerspoon

According to [the docs](http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.alert.html), I should be able to close an alert with a fadeout:

```
hs.alert.closeAll([seconds])

hs.alert.closeSpecific(uuid, [seconds])
```

But no matter what I try, the alert just seems to close immediately (so it's never even visible).

```
local uuid = hs.alert.show("test", {fillColor = {red = 1}}, 5.0)
hs.alert.closeSpecific(uuid, 0.5)
```

I've tried both `closeAll` and `closeSpecific`, as well as fade times lesser and greater than the alert's duration. I'm on the latest Hammerspoon (0.9.73).

Comment: Have you changed the `fadeInDuration` for the `hs.alert.defaultStyle` from the default of 0.15?

Comment: Hm, why should that matter though? Shouldn't an explicit parameter override the default?

Comment: You pass a specific parameter for the `fadeOutDuration` not the `fadeInDuration` I am just curious if you made any adjustments to the fade in.

Comment: Oh the fadein, sorry. No, that's untouched.